# Heat balance multilayer with heat flux continuity

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, heat-equation

I am solving the heat equation (diffusion only) over a 3-layer system (physical properties varying from layer to layer).

```
km = 0.128;
rhom = 925;
Cpm = 1550;

ka = 0.024;
rhoa = 1.292;
Cpa = 1003;

thickness = 2*0.136;   
L1 = N[-thickness/2];
L2 = N[thickness/2];
T01 = 120;
T02 = 20;
T03 = 120;

Length1 = 0.5; 

v= 40/60;

time1 = Length1/v;
```

For describing the properties change in space, I use the following equation:

```
slope = 1000;
SmoothedStepFunction[fL_, fmax_, fR_, tsL_, tsR_, m_] := 
 Function[t, (fL*Exp[tsL*m] + fmax*Exp[m*t])/(Exp[tsL*m] + 
     Exp[m*t]) - (fR*Exp[tsR*m] + fmax*Exp[m*t])/(Exp[tsR*m] + 
     Exp[m*t]) + fR];

rhoCp[x_] := 
  SmoothedStepFunction[rhoa*Cpa, rhom*Cpm, rhoa*Cpa, L1, L2, slope][x];
k[x_] := SmoothedStepFunction[10^6*ka, 10^6*km, 10^6*ka, L1, L2, 
    slope][x];
```

The actual heat balance is solved here:

```
heateq = rhoCp[x]*D[u[x, t], t] == 
   Inactive[Div][{{k[x]}}.Inactive[Grad][u[x, t], {x}], {x}];

ic[x_] := 
  Piecewise[{{T01, x < L1}, {T02, L1 <= x <= L2}, {T03, x > L2}}];

sol1 = First[
   NDSolve[{heateq, u[x, 0] == ic[x]}, 
    u, {x, -2*thickness, 2*thickness}, {t, 0, time1}, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
        "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}]];
```

Despite it works well, I still have a question: next to the heat flux continuity over the boundaries of materials (`Inactive[Div][{{k[x]}}.Inactive[Grad][u[x, t]`), are there other boundary conditions applied implicitly with this approach?

Comment: Currently, Mathematica does not support Neumann values on interfaces. It will, however, maintain heat flux continuity across a material interface.

Comment: in the formulation above, when does ```Inactive[]``` become active?

Comment: Form the documentation [Numerical Solution of Partial Differential Equations](https://wolfram.com/xid/0sloo4bz49-044fyf), "Inactive forms can be activated using Activate, but commands like NDSolve can also work with the inactive forms directly." It is usually best to express the FEM operator in [Coefficient Form](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#1222366601).  Because `Div`/`Grad` evaluate immediately, the coefficient form is lost without `Inactive`, but `NDSolve` can process it.

Comment: by using ```Inactive[]``` I can leave out two boundaries conditions. why?

Comment: The default BC for a FEM problem is `NeumannValue[0, (x == xmin || x == xmax)]`, which is an insulated wall.  If you supply no BCs, the default will be assumed.  `Inactive` does not change the default value.